# How to open safari without saving cookies

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When i m open my `Safari` using `WebDriver` and go into my desire site it always 
save `Cookies` so is it possible to open safari without saving `Cookies` ?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has no support to programmatically disable cookies in Safari so far. You have to manually disable it. You can try the following methods:

**1.** Write code which will delete all the files from the Safari folder. Something like this:

```
def clearCache():
    """This will just delete the files straight from the safari folder, guarentee a clean start"""
    try:
        #Using rm command assuming you are using MacOS
        os.system("rm -rf $HOME/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/*.localstorage")
    except Exception, e:
        log.error("Error in clearCache: %s" %e)
```

**2.** Or you could manually disable cookies from the settings for a particular profile and then use that profile to initiate your Safari WebDriver.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/selenium-users/EmCp4pcbuPU/hvErelouhd4J)